# Synology Directory Server (SAMBA4) - change Password on Website

Tags: active-directory, synology, samba-dc

I'm using the Synology Directory Server (Samba) as Active Directory in our local voluntary fire brigade for our Client PCs, Internal Website, MediaWiki, WLAN,...

Most of our users don't use the client PCs with windows and just use the passwords form outside via websites. What is the best way to allow them to change their passwords via a website?
Fastest would be to make the NAS accessible from outside and change the password their, but that's my security worst case - so no option.

I thought that this wouldn't be a big deal with a small homepage, hosted locally and make accessible from outside to change the passwords, but i couldn't find anything...

thanks
Manuel